# How to create a shorcut for Volume Mixer on Windows 11?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, shortcuts, volume-mixer

It used to be that to open up Volume Mixer in Windows one needed only 2 moves, specifically, right-click the volume icon at the bottom right corner of the desktop and then choose Volume Mixer.

In Windows 11 (22H2) I need to do 5 (!) moves to open up Volume Mixer. Specifically, I have to left-click the Internet + Volume icon at the bottom right corner, press on "Select a sound output", press "More volume settings", scroll down, and finally reach Volume Mixer.

The worst thing is that I cannot seem to create a shortcut for this service. If I pin the window in the taskbar, the next time I open it up I found myself in the Taskbar settings menu.

Is there a way to create either a) a desktop/taskbar shortcut or b) a keyboard shortcut for Volume Mixer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume mixer is the executable `SndVol.exe`.

You could give it a shortcut key via various means.
For example, create a desktop icon for `SndVol.exe`,
right-click it, select Properties, and in the Shortcut tab give it
a Shortcut key.

Comment: And call the Sound dialog by `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL Mmsys.cpl,,0` See https://woshub.com/ms-settings-uri-commands-windows-11/ for more such setting calls.